# How to delete points drawn by command "plt.plot(x,y)"

Tags: python, matplotlib, points

I just want to  delete points drawed by command "plt.plot(x,y)" in python package matplotlib.Would you give me some specific commands

```
            x,y=self.forward(x,y,v,target1)
            print a
            print x,y
            plt.plot(x, y, '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete points from a line. Three options you have:

- **Remove the plot, create new plot**

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

  x=np.array([1,3,4,6,7])
  y=np.array([2,2,2,2,2])

  line, = plt.plot(x, y, '*')

  #points to keep
  ind = [True,True,False,False,True]

  line.remove()
  newx = x[ind]
  newy = y[ind]
  line, = plt.plot(newx, newy, '*')

  plt.show()
  ```
- **Update data**

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

  x=np.array([1,3,4,6,7])
  y=np.array([2,2,2,2,2])

  line, = plt.plot(x, y, '*')

  #points to keep
  ind = [True,True,False,False,True]

  newx = x[ind]
  newy = y[ind]
  line.set_data(newx, newy)

  plt.show()
  ```
- **Mark only subset of points**

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

  x=np.array([1,3,4,6,7])
  y=np.array([2,2,2,2,2])

  line, = plt.plot(x, y, '*')

  #points to keep
  ind = [True,True,False,False,True]

  line.set_markevery(ind)

  plt.show()
  ```

Comment: Sorry so much.Thank you for you answer,but my discription are not clearly.I have add more details .Could you give me some resolution

Comment: Sorry, you completely changed the question. This invalidates all given answers to the original question.

Comment: I also feel upset, my careless causes the misunderstand

Comment: I rolled back the question. You may ask a new question about your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Ernest said: "You cannot delete points from a line".

If you want to do this for some kind of animation, take a look at the [animation module](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)

Another *highly not recommended hack* would be 'paint over' the point with a color equal to the background.

```
x_del = x[2]
y_del = y[2]
plt.plot(x_del, y_del, '*', color='white')
```

Comment: Sorry so much.Thank you for you answer,but my discription are not clearly.I have add more details .Could you give me some resolution